# Caching strategies

Tags: caching, outputcache

Browser caching

Full page caching

Edge side includes (ESI)

Application output caching

Application object caching

Database query caching

Some caching strategies - I pretty much understand all of them but application object caching? How do I decide which one is the best?

I just want to figure out a good mix - for good performance and scalability.

Comment: Please include some concrete use cases to be discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all orthogonal. The caches you describe can all be implemented at the same time. More caching is generally better. Computer systems have caches on all levels, from multiple levels of memory caches inside the CPU all the way up to the application or data specific caches you describe here. Which one to implement first depends heavily on what data is expensive to calculate or fetch, how often that data is used and how much you can speed it up by caching it.

The key to a good cache is that it should be much faster than the work it is caching, and it should cache stuff which is often reused. You must also have a way of pruning expired data from the cache.

---

`Application Object Caching` refers to objects which are transferred between different layers (different programs, computers in a cluster etc). These objects may be cached on the receiving end so they won't need to be transferred on every access.

Comment: memcached is a specific tool which may help you implement a cache. You can store both objects and pages in it - it's up to you!

Comment: OK I see - cool : ) Different layers do you mean network layers ?